# Python : Filter dataframe rows based on multiple dynamic column values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter rows of my dataframe based on a list of column values. The problem with this is, I have the length of columns coming in dynamically and so far I have tried this and this won't serve my purpose.

```
>>>df
    a      b
0  jdfb  sdvkb
```

If I have to search on both the columns at once. That is if `a='jdfb'` AND `b='sdvkb'` then I need to return 1.

I have the search columns created dynamically stored in a list variable `fields` and the values also in another list variable 'matchlist`.

```
fields = ['a','b']
matchlist = ['jdfb','sdvkb']
```

**Approach 1** I tried this and it worked:

```
>>> df[fields].isin(matchlist)
    a     b
0  True  True
```

This is fine. This is actually exactly what I want. But when I tried the next query, that was not what I wanted because it shouldn't have worked:

```
>>> df[fields].isin(matchlist)
    a     b
0  True  True
```

The problem with this approach is that the columns should match in the order specified in **approach 1** and not in the next way I tried. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: can you show your all data

Comment: you want a='jdfb' AND b='sdvkb' match in whole dataFrame?

Comment: @ammy Yes I want that condition applied on my dataframe. All my data is just description. It could be anything. And the values that I should be searching can be anything. I was just giving you sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to generate two separate boolean indices and combine them.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> #create the mapping of desirable values
... desirable = ['a','b']
>>> 
>>> #create data where some rows match the conditions
... data = [desirable,desirable[::-1],desirable, desirable, desirable[::-1]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['first','second'])
>>> 
>>> #Rows 0, 2, and 3 match our conditions
... df
  first second
0     a      b
1     b      a
2     a      b
3     a      b
4     b      a
>>> 
>>> #create a boolean mask for rows that match our conditions
... conditions = (df['first'] == desirable[0]) & (df['second'] == desirable[1])
>>> 
>>> #we can now use this boolean mask to get the desired rows
... df[conditions]
  first second
0     a      b
2     a      b
3     a      b
>>>
```

Comment: It is not 2 fields only that I have to search for. Sometimes it can be only 1 field or maybe on 3 fields. The dataframe has more than 2 columns

Comment: You could either manually write conditions that work with more columns or you could use some logic to enumerate and iterate over the columns, comparing each to the respective value in the list of desired column values.